# What are the stats of Dracula (final boss, Symphony of the Night)?

Tags: castlevania-symphony-of-the-night

Dracula, and his servant, Shaft, make up the final boss fight of Symphony of the Night, and actually put up a challenge. However, due to how the cutscenes work at the end, you can't go back to the Library and view their stats. Due to this, I never figured out how much health they had. Does anyone know what their stats are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki says that [Dracula](https://castlevania.fandom.com/wiki/Dracula/Symphony_of_the_Night#Enemy_Data) has 9999 HP, while [Shaft](https://castlevania.fandom.com/wiki/Shaft#Castlevania:_Symphony_of_the_Night_2) has 1300.